# Evaluate integral using contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have some troubles in solving integral
$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z^2+2z+b}$.
The tip is to use integral $\int_{C}\frac{\ln{z} dz}{z^2+2z+b}$. Can't understand, why we have $\ln{z}$ in nominator. Can someone explain this move? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $C$ winds around the branch of log .. on one  side of the branch you have $\ln x$ and on the other you have $\ln x + \pi i$. The real parts (ones involving the $ln$ terms cancel each other)

Comment: @r9m so, how to solve it?